# How to document a no-SQL database model?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, model, nosql, documentation

When developing a relational database model for an application one can create for example an [entity-relationship model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model), e.g. using MySQL Workbench. Although documenting those models using UML class diagrams is also very common. Both methods can be seen as *standard* way to go when making up an architecture for a project.

**Question: what is the *standard* way to go for no-SQL database models?**

I want to design a model for MongoDB and/or ElasticSearch which are basically arbitrary JSON stores. But I need to document at least the fields and the "relations" to each other to give a reference structure.

Is there any tool (diagram language?) existing? I looked into the documentations and found no hint for an answer. I'm aware of text files and know that one could simply write a text file with an example JSON. But I'm looking for a little bit more sophisticated and polished solution.

Any ideas or *standards* here?

Answer (score 0):

[Moon Modeler](https://www.datensen.com/) for MongoDB is a tool for visual definition of noSQL structures. It allows you to draw diagrams similar to entity relationship diagrams - with nested types/embedded documents.